# Custom Unsaved Data Warning for react-router-dom BrowserRouter

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-router-dom

I'm trying to listen to URL changes in my Redux app. If you have unsaved data on your form when attempting to change the route, I'd like a custom warning message to appear. If the user selects cancel, I'd like it to NOT change the route. How is this accomplished?

I see `getUserConfirmation`. The examples show that it takes a message and a callback. But my code is demanding zero parameters and a void return type.

How do I intercept routing events?

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that TypeScript's definition did not match the underlying code.

So I used my magical skeleton key for all things TypeScript: `any`!

Set it up like this:

`<Router getUserConfirmation={getUserConfirmation}>`

Then I did something similar to the following:

```
const getUserConfirmation: any = (message: string, callback: (answer: boolean) => void) => {
  ReactDOM.render(
    <MyCustomDialog
      onOkClicked={buildOkClicked(callback)}
      onClose={buildCloseModal(callback)}
      onClose={buildCloseModal(callback)}
    />,
    someDiv
  )
}

const buildCloseModal = (callback: (answer: boolean) => void) => {
  return () => {
    closeModal()
    callback(false)
  }
}

const buildOkClicked = (callback: (answer: boolean) => void) => {
  return () => {
    closeModal()
    callback(true)
  }
}

const closeModal = () => {
  ReactDOM.render(
    <div />,
    someDiv
  )
}
```

***The key here is when declaring getUserConfirmation, use ": any" to get past any compilation issues***